# Animate showing and hiding login box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a jquery animated loginbox.

I am a total javascript/jquery noob.

I have a div that contains the loginbox. That div is about 150px in height, and it is placed at the top of the page, so that only the bottom 15px of the div are visible when the page is loaded.

I am trying to slide down the div so that the rest of the login box is revealed on click, and make it slide back up when the bottom part of the div is clicked again.

Now, I am doing:

```
$('#showLogin').click(function(e){
$('#formContainer').animate({top: "+=135px"} , 1500)
e.preventDefault()
})
```

What this does is animate the slide down of the div. But how can I check if it has already been slided down so I can slide it back up?

Should I check for the position of the div and decide if it should move up or down, or is there a better way to do it?

The website is [here](http://www.portofinokouzina.gr/)

Comment: "Should I check for the position of the div and decide if it should move up or down, or is there a better way to do it?" I'd say that's the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: What if the trigger div is clicked again, before it's animation has finished though?

Comment: It depends on what you want it to do. You could ignore the click and let the animation continue, or make the click retract the div. jQuery is pretty flexible that way ;)

Comment: So doing

    if($('#formContainer').css('top') == "135"){
        //slide the div up
    }
    else{
        //slide the div down}
Will get it done?

Comment: Do you want the login box to completely slide up and disappear off the page when the user clicks it, or just slide back up to the original position where only 15px of it are visible?

Comment: The second, so that clicking will show the box, and clicking again will revert the previous action and return the box to its initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SC6E9/) example. It animates a div with a form within it on click, and retracts it once it's fully extended.

The basic jQuery is:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).css('top')
    if (!$(this).is(':animated')) {
        if (parseInt(pos, 10) == 0) {
            $(this).animate({'top': '-35px'});  // anim up 
        }
        else {
            $(this).animate({'top': '0px'}); //anim down
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle). An example: http://jsfiddle.net/FL4zZ/

Comment: It is helpful but it does not work in this case, since the div that when clicked shows the login box, is inside the login box. So when I try .slideToggle, the div disappears. I have uploaded the javascript file and you can see the effect of slideToggle on the link on the question.